# Streaming M3U8 To Instagram Live

Tags: instagram

I've never tried Instagram and I'm just thinking of creating a page which I stream some events to my followers.

I want to be able to use M3U8 links/files to be directly accessed by Instagram so that is able to read directly from the file/link.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer Sorry man, won't happen again.